# Show that $\lim _{n \rightarrow+\infty} \sup _{x \in[0,1]}\left|f(x)-\mathcal{P}_{n}(x)\right|=0$

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, uniform-convergence, approximation

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ and for any $n \geq 1$ let us define the polynomial function :
$$
\mathcal{P}_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) x^{k}(1-x)^{n-k} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
$$

For any $x \in[0,1]$ let $\left(\varepsilon_{n}(x)\right)_{n>1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulii r.v. of parameter $x$. Let then $S_{n}(x)=\varepsilon_{1}(x)+\cdots+\varepsilon_{n}(x)$.

$\mathcal{P}_{n}(x)$ can be interpreted as the following expectation : $$\mathbb{E}[f(\frac{S_n(x)}{n})]$$

By using Bienaymé-Chebychev's inequality we can show that :
$$
\forall \varepsilon>0, \quad \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{S_{n}(x)}{n}-x\right| \geq \varepsilon\right) \leq \frac{1}{4 n \varepsilon^{2}}
$$

thus $\frac{S_{n}(x)}{n}$ converges in probability and thus in distribution to $x$, consequently $\mathcal{P}_{n}(x)$ converges to $E[f(x)] = f(x)$, I'm not sure how to establish the convergence with the supremum as stated in the title though, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $\zeta_n(x) = S_n(x)/n$. For any $\varepsilon>0$,
$$
\bigl|\mathrm{E}[f(\zeta_n(x)] - f(x)\bigr|\le \mathrm{E}\left[\bigl|f(\zeta_n(x))-f(x)\bigr| \right] \\= \mathrm{E}\left[\bigl|f(\zeta_n(x))-f(x)\bigr|\mathbf{1}_{|\zeta_n(x)-x|\le \varepsilon} \right] + \mathrm{E}\left[\bigl|f(\zeta_n(x))-f(x)\bigr|\mathbf{1}_{|\zeta_n(x)-x|> \varepsilon} \right]\\
\le \omega_f(\varepsilon) + 2\sup|f| \cdot \mathrm{P}(|\zeta_n(x)-x|> \varepsilon),
$$
where $\omega_f(\varepsilon) = \sup_{0\le s<t<s+\varepsilon\le 1}|f(t) - f(s)|$ is the modulus of coninuity of $f$.

I believe you can conclude from here, using Chebyshev's inequality.